# Is there a way to hide multiple html tags with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering if there is any easy way to toggle HTML elements with Javascript? I have a bunch of ascii art for one of my projects I'm making, I need an efficient way to show/hide it without repeating the same line a million times.

This is a little snippet of the offending code:

```
  function dagger(){
  document.getElementById("short").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("long").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("broad").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("choose").style.display = "none";
  /* all the stats and modifiers go here */
}

function short(){
  document.getElementById("dagger").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("long").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("broad").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("choose").style.display = "none";
  /* all the stats and modifiers go here */
}

function long(){
  document.getElementById("short").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("dagger").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("broad").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("choose").style.display = "none";
  /* all the stats and modifiers go here */
}

function broad(){
  document.getElementById("short").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("long").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("dagger").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("choose").style.display = "none";
  /* all the stats and modifiers go here */
}
```

As you can see, it's really clunky and huge. I tried setting the id to a variable and calling it from within the functions like this:

```
var dagger = getElementById("dagger");
var short = getElementById("short");

function dagger(){
  short.style.display = "none";
}
```

But that wouldn't work for some reason. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any specific reason not to use [getElementsByClassName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) ?

Comment: thanks for the ideas, I'll look into manipulating classes. This is all super new to me so I didn't even know I could group a class into an array.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the commenters that you should be using classes for this, the answer to your question is that you are calling `getElementById` when you need to still call `document.getElementById`

```js
var long = function() {
  document.getElementById("short").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("long").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("broad").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("choose").style.display = "none";
  /* all the stats and modifiers go here */
}

var short = document.getElementById("short");

var dagger = function() {
 short.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="short">short</div>
<div id="long">long</div>
<div id="broad">broad</div>
<div id="choose">choose</div>

<button onclick="long()">long</button>
<button onclick="dagger()">dagger</button>
```

Comment: In my files, it was document.getElementById(""); i found out it wasn't working because I was naming the variable the same as the function, so I switched them all to daggerView, shortView, etc... and it works properly now. I didn't realize it until your solution though, thanks.